# ANSI Encoding Issue

Tags: c#, encoding

I was reading a file using the below code 
The file is in ANSI encode

```
string strReadTheWholeFile = 
    File.ReadAllText(txtFilePath.Text.ToString(),Encoding.GetEncoding(1250));
```

Once read and fetched into a string i use the below code to replace a string in the file

```
strReadTheWholeFile = strReadTheWholeFile.Replace(
    "PortableSpecFileVersion=5.0;", ":ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ:");
```

Once replaced i save back the file using the below code

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\MK\Converted\" + Path.GetFileName(txtFilePath.Text.ToString()),
    strReadTheWholeFile, Encoding.GetEncoding(1250));
```

Once saved i open the file to see whether the changes have been committed or not but what i found is that the string is replaced but its been replaced wrong

Original String:

> PortableSpecFileVersion=5.0;ConversionName=GSKPrePayValidation;

Replaced String:

> :yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy:ConversionName=GSKPrePayValidation;

As you can see the i wanted to replace it with "ÿ" but instead it was replaced by "y"
Can any one suggest what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

[ÿ does not exist in the codepage you're reading and writing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250), so it gets replaced. It does seem to exist in [1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), though.

Answer (score 1):

According to the reference page on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195052.aspx), the `ÿ` character does not exist in that set.

You could use an encoding that you know could handle it, like UTF8: *(tested, works)*

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\MK\Converted\" + Path.GetFileName(txtFilePath.Text.ToString()),
                  strReadTheWholeFile, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: Grant is tried using UTF8 for reading as well while writing but there is a different issue i faced while doing the same. My file which is read also contain line which contains some characters like "ÿÿ¤" and when i use UTF8 to read and save the file the replacement happens but this characters in the original file get converted to "˙˙¤" this character in the target file

Comment: @joey <br/> your suggestion with 1252 worked. Can you guys also suggest me some reading material online which will help me in improving my knowledge in encoding as i work a lot with file processing software